# CMS integrating ASP.Net MVC 2 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, content-management-system

I have created ASP.Net MVC 2 application. To manage the content on ViewPages I want to integrate with Content Management System.Is there any such CMS?

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [Orchard CMS](http://orchardproject.net/) which is built on top of ASP.NET MVC. There are also [N2Cms](http://n2cms.com/) and [Kooboo](http://www.kooboo.com/) to name a few.